# Orbeon Form Builder - Result dialog

Tags: orbeon

I want to know how to add a result dialog to my form created using Orbeon Forms' Form Builder. I have a `send` button which will send an email with the attached PDF and XML files. And once that button is clicked I want to display two result dialog boxes, one for successfully mail sent and another for failure. In the property file I have added the following code

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.MonashHealth.*"
    value='
        require-valid
        then save-final
        then email
        then xf:show("result-dialog")
        recover navigate("http://localhost:8080/examples/jsp/jsp2/tagfiles/failure.jsp")
    '/>
```

But this does not display any dialog box on sending the email successfully.

Comment: Did you define a dialog with id `result-dialog`? Also, you're saying that you'd like to show a different dialog in case of success versus failure, however your code shows a dialog in case of success but goes to a page in case of failure. I imagine that if you'd like to show a dialog in that second case, you should have `recover xf:show('my-failure-dialog')` instead of `recover navigate(…)`.

Comment: Thank you @avernet, is my failure dialog a per-defined dialog box? or do we have to define it? if so how and where?

Comment: There is an `fr-error-dialog` that you could use. The simplest way to show it is with the XPath function `frf:errorMessage('your error message')`. You can see how it is used in [`components/view.xsl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/components/view.xsl).

Comment: Thank you @avernet! I also want to know how the result dialog box work, I followed http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/predefined.html#the-result-dialog   and according to it OK button can be defined, I want to know what is the action of OK button and will it close the browser tab? Is there a way to close the browser tab when OK button of result dialog is clicked? Is there any other way to achieve this? Also want to know how to define the properties for OK button of result dialog in properties-local.xml file? Please need help

Comment: Are you referring to *OK* button of the `fr-error-dialog` dialog? You can't control what this button does without changing Form Runner.